# ¿Cuál es la forma abreviada de representar condicionales en JavaScript sin utilizar 'if-else'?

Tags: javascript

Estoy interesada en aprender sobre las técnicas de JavaScript para representar condicionales de manera más concisa, evitando el uso excesivo de declaraciones 'if-else'. ¿Qué métodos y operadores puedo utilizar para simplificar las lógicas condicionales en mi código JavaScript?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Brevedad no necesariamente es sinónimo de legibilidad. En la práctica no se busca eficiencia, sino legibilidad. Sugiero que aprendas de código limpio. Un primer paso es reemplazar código repetido por funciones, y los **nombres**, es muy importante utilizar nombres descriptivos.

Answer (score 2):

En JavaScript, puedes utilizar operadores ternarios y expresiones lógicas para representar condicionales de forma abreviada sin utilizar estructuras `if-else`. Aquí te muestro cómo hacerlo:

1. Operador Ternario (`?`):

   El operador ternario es una forma concisa de expresar una condición y devolver un valor basado en esa condición. Su sintaxis es la siguiente:

   ```javascript
   condicion ? valorSiCierto : valorSiFalso;
   ```

   Ejemplo:

   ```javascript
   var edad = 20;
   var mensaje = (edad >= 18) ? 'Eres mayor de edad' : 'Eres menor de edad';
   console.log(mensaje); // Esto mostrará "Eres mayor de edad"
   ```
2. Expresiones Lógicas (`&&` y `||`):

   Puedes utilizar las expresiones lógicas `&&` (y) y `||` (o) para realizar acciones basadas en condiciones. Por ejemplo:

   - Usando `&&` para realizar una acción si ambas condiciones son verdaderas:

     ```javascript
     condicion1 && condicion2 && accionSiAmbasVerdaderas;
     ```
   - Usando `||` para realizar una acción si al menos una de las condiciones es verdadera:

     ```javascript
     condicion1 || condicion2 || accionSiAlMenosUnaVerdadera;
     ```

   Ejemplo:

   ```javascript
   var esAdulto = true;
   var tieneLicencia = false;

   esAdulto && tieneLicencia && console.log('Puede conducir'); // No se mostrará nada porque la segunda condición es falsa

   var esMiembro = true;
   var tieneDescuento = false;

   esMiembro || tieneDescuento || console.log('No tiene descuento'); // No se mostrará nada porque al menos una condición es verdadera
   ```

Estas son algunas de las formas abreviadas comunes para representar condicionales en JavaScript sin utilizar la estructura `if-else`. La elección entre ellas depende de la lógica que quieras expresar en tu código y de tus preferencias personales.

Espero te sirva esta respuesta

Comment: Muy bien la respuesta